# What is the text command for naming a window in gnu-screen?

Tags: gnu-screen, window-title

I have created a long running screen session with many windows and the `C-a A` command to rename a window is not working. What is the text command for renaming a window?

I have tried `:caption string windowname` but it doesn't work. Is that the right command or am I missing something?

Comment: does this answer your question? http://superuser.com/questions/370510/rename-screen-session

Comment: That question is for changing the name of the session. My question is about renaming the windows within the session

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the **`title`** command, e.g,.

```
:title bad-window
```

In the manual:

> **`title`** *[windowtitle]*
>
> Set the name of the current window to *windowtitle*. If no name is specified, *`screen`* prompts for one. This command was known as **`aka`** in previous releases.

If the shortcut is not working, of course, the long name may not work either.

Comment: The shortcut was not working but the `title` command worked. Something must have happened to screen's key handling. How many windows can be run within `screen`

Comment: I had become so accustomed to `C-a A` that I had forgotten that there was command line alternative

Answer (score 1):

Also there is a very simple handy **cheat-sheet** designed for screen using its own `help` command‌ (<kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd>`:help` or <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd>) which helps to remember all shortcuts and their actions:

In your case the shortcut key <kbd>A</kbd> is assigned to keyword `title` on its help. (Just needs to remember all documented shortcut keys require to press <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd> or `(C-a)` before being pressed.)